# Como abrir um novo arquivo html na mesma aba?

Tags: javascript, html5, comandos

Eu gostaria de saber como abrir um novo arquivo html na mesma aba, porém por comando. Eu já usei o window.open(), mas ele mantem a guia aberta e abre uma nova.

Não gostaria de utilizar a tag "a"

Answer (score 4):

Também pode trocar a localização usando [location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

```
location.replace("nova url");
```

```js
function replace() {
  location.replace("https://pt.stackoverflow.com", "_self");
}
```

```html
<button id="replace" onclick="replace()">Clique em mim para substituir a url</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.open("seuURL", "_self");`

Documentação da Mozilla sobre isso

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

```html
<button onclick="funk()">Abrir</button>

<script>
function funk() {
  window.open("https://pt.stackoverflow.com", "_self");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usar `window.open` para abrir uma página na mesma aba, ao meu ver, não faz muito sentido, se a função principal desse método é justamente abrir uma nova aba.

Você poderia usar `location` no `onclick`. Não é muito necessária uma função pra isso, e você pode fazer tudo no próprio botão de forma mais simplificada:

```html
<button onclick="location = 'outra_pagina.html'">Ir</button>
```

O `location` irá redirecionar a página para onde você quiser, seja uma página interna ou um site externo. Só que para ir para um site externo, é preciso colocar o protocolo (ex., `https://`). Ex: `location = 'https://google.com'`.